# ¿Es necesaria la existencia de la etiqueta [ejercicio]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

La verdad no estoy seguro de que la existencia de esta etiqueta sea de utilidad para realizar algún filtro, actualmente existen 17 preguntas utilizando esta etiqueta según veo y no tiene wiki.

En mi opinión no es necesario saber si una pregunta es o no un ejercicio (o tal vez a alguien si le es importante saber esto de una pregunta, no lo sé).

¿Valdría la pena eliminar esta etiqueta? o ¿Hay algún motivo por la que es necesaria?

Comment: Kill it!!!! eliminala!!! hacela desaparecer!!!.. no, yo siento que no aporta nada....

Comment: sucede lo mismo con la etiqueta tarea: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tarea

Comment: me parece que; si se trataran de asignaciones escolares: proyectos, tareas, ejercicios... deberían englobarse en una sola etiqueta ... algo como `[asignación-escolar]` o `[asignación-educativa]`

Comment: en que ayuda esta etiqueta:a los que estan interesados en ser docentes en el area de tecnologia... puedan ayudar a estudiantes, que vengan a hacer preguntas aqui; aunque el sitio no se dedica a hacerle la tarea a nadie, no esta descartado... solo que para tal fin el OP requiere colocar en su post todo lo necesario y relacionado a la tarea, ejercicio o proyecto incluyendo donde esta atorado.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 tienes razón tendríamos que considerar la etiqueta tarea también.

Comment: Tal y como lo menciona @ArcanisGK507, la etiqueta [tarea] no tiene ningún uso en concreto y no aporta nada a la comunidad, me he tomado la tarea de quemarla :).

Comment: tambien hay que quemar la de php y la de python

Comment: no aportan nada si no se usa las etiquetas de version php7 por ejemplo...

Comment: En general, una pregunta es una pregunta (bella tautología) sin importar si el que la hace está haciendo sus deberes, es un principiante, es una persona en una oficina con un rol que no implica programar, etc. El por qué de la pregunta es un detalle ontológico que posiblemente escapa al objetivo de SOes.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 en desacuerdo, las etiquetas del lenguaje no se puede quemar, en su lugar, recomendar (en la meta wiki por ejemplo) que debe adicionarse siempre la version sobre la que se trabaja, tal como pasa con las etiquetas de [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap-4/info)

Comment: @JheymanMejia hay que quemar todas las meta etiquetas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cierro tema ya que la etiqueta fue quemada semanas atrás y de todas formas se llegó a 12 votos positivos y 1 negativo que creo es suficiente para dar por sentado que la etiqueta no era de gran utilidad.

Answer (score 9):

En definitiva, no le veo utilidad a la etiqueta.

De hecho, es una meta-etiqueta; si se revisa [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](/help/tagging) se puede leer:

> Si la etiqueta no puede trabajar como la única etiqueta en una pregunta, es probablemente una meta-etiqueta.

No tiene wiki ni orientación de uso, y consta de [17 preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ejercicio) (08/04/2022) ─tal como se menciona en la pregunta─. Su eliminación sería justa.

*¡A quemarla!*

Answer (score 5):

Alguna vez he hablado con otros compañeros veteranos de stackexchange acerca de una etiqueta o incluso un mecanismo más fuerte que refleje el ámbito académico en una pregunta. Los defensores de ese nuevo mecanismo consideran lo siguiente:

> Muchas veces se plantean problemas de algoritmia, estructura de datos,
> etc que suelen tener una solución sencilla en el lenguaje que se
> trabaja, quizás con su propia implementación. Por ejemplo, imaginemos
> un usuario que está estudiando cómo implementar una lista enlazada en
> Java, mientras que la respuesta del mundo real podría ser sugerirle el
> uso de LinkedList, una respuesta en contexto académico incluiría los
> fundamentos y la elaboración de un código funcional.

Es decir, sugieren un mecanismo que refleje que es una pregunta que surge en contexto académico (un "ejercicio"), a fin de fomentar explicaciones más elaboradas y ceñirse al código o enunciado sugerido por el usuario que pregunta y no simplemente a lo estándar.

Sin embargo, la realidad es que se distingue muy bien cuando un usuario quiere ceñirse a una forma de trabajar o un contexto académico. Puede reflejarlo por escrito en su propia pregunta, e incluso si no lo hace en un primer momento, puede editarla para aclarar mejor cuando las respuestas no le convencen.

Luego, yo considero que esos mecanismos, incluyendo la etiqueta "ejercicio" (meta-etiqueta por definición) no tienen sentido y debería quemarse.